# Как работает __getattr__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясните ,пожалуйста, **откуда берется 4 и как она передается в список**? Главный вопрос про 4, а не общий алгоритм работы данного метода.

Код:

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object
    def  __getattr__(self, attrname):
        print('Trace:',  type(attrname))
        print(self.wrapped)
        return  getattr(self.wrapped, attrname) #  Но где 4 здесь? Как ее можно отловить внутри wrapper? 
x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])
x. append(4) # тут 4 передается
print(x.wrapped)
```

Вывод:

```
Trace: <class 'str'>
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Как я понял метод `__getattr__` - вызывается, когда запрашивается отсутствующее свойство класса.

функция `getattr` - пытается вызвать метод или свойство у передаваемого объекта.

Но каким образом туда передается 4? Как ее отловить внутри `__getattr__` ?

Просто сравниваю с `__call` из php и там передаются атрибуты вызываемого метода (т.е. 4), а тут нет, но в то же время они как то передались.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Внутрь самого `__getattr__` число 4 и не попадает.

Смотрите, что происходит:

1. Интерпретатор встречает код `x.append(4)`
2. Он понимает, что ему нужно взять функцию `x.append` и вызвать её с аргументом 4
3. Чтобы понять, что такое `x.append`, он пытается обратиться к атрибуту `append` объекта `x`, и проваливается в `__getattr__` этого объекта.
4. `__getattr__` говорит интерпретатору, что `x.append` - это тупо `append` того списка, который хранится внутри враппера.
5. Интерпретатор ВЫХОДИТ из `__getattr__` и только полсле этого скармливает 4 методу `append` списка, который хранится внутри враппера.

То есть 4 внутрь `__getattr__` просто не попадает вообще никак.

Если хочется отлавливать аргументы, то из `__getattr__` нужно возвращать не сам метод, а некоторую обёртку вокруг него, в которой и будет логика отлавливания аргумента:

```
class Wrapper:

    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object

    def  __getattr__(self, attrname):

        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            print('Got it!!!', args, kwargs)  # Вот здесь 4 уже можно отловить
            return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)(*args, **kwargs)

        return func


x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])
x.append(4)
print(x.wrapped)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не совсем всё понял, но это тот ответ, которого я ждал.

Comment: Видимо return  getattr(self.wrapped, attrname) возвращает не результат append, а некий билдер метода, ну или ссылку на метод, в который уже интерпретатор передает параметры. 
Вот здесь я запутался, а сейчас начинает доходить.

Comment: В питоне не используют термин "ссылка". Боле правильное объяснение такое: В питоне функция является полноценным объектом, который можно возвращать в качестве значения, присваивать переменной и т.п. В том числе, функция может быть и атрибутом объекта и класса. При этом обычно метод объекта - это просто атрибут-функция, которая замкнута на этот объект. Соответственно вы можете взять метод списка, передать его в какое-то другое место, и уже там вызвать с аргументом 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):            # [3]
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)  # [4]

x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])  # [1]
x.append(4)             # [2]
print(x.wrapped)
```

- `[1]` Вы передали в класс список
- `[2]` У объекта класса обратились к атрибуту `append`
- `[3]` В `__getattr__` вы обрабатываете случай обращения к неизвестному атрибуту, а в `attrname` попадет строка `append`
- `[4]` Вы вернули атрибут у списка `[1]` по строке `append`

Т.е. вы попросту у списка в `self.wrapped` вызвали его метод `append` и в него передали `4`

---

**PS.**

Так можно и другие атрибуты у любых объектов вызывать, например:

```
x = Wrapper(dict(a=1))
x.update(dict(b=2))
print(x.wrapped)  # {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

---

**UPD.**

Добавил обертку над функцией, что возвращается объектом `self.wrapped` через `__getattr__` таким образом будет вызываться наш метод и он получит параметры, а после сам вызовет функцию `self.wrapped`:

```
class Wrapper:
    def _root_decorator(self, func, attrname):
        def _wrapper_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            print(attrname, *args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return _wrapper_decorator

    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object

    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        func = getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)
        return self._root_decorator(func, attrname)

x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])
x.append(4)
print(x.wrapped)
# append 4
# [1, 2, 3, 4]

x = Wrapper(dict(a=1))
x.update(dict(b=2))
print(x.wrapped)
# update {'b': 2}
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Проверку того, что `func` является функцией оставляю на автора вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, общий алгоритм мне был понятен, мне не понятно как передается "4"?
return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname). Тут передается список и строка "append", как передается 4 ? Как например передать в внутренний список 4+1 ? Не снаружи, а именно изнутри

Comment: @Pavel, обновил ответ

Comment: благодарю! буду изучать

Comment: @Pavel, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: я проголосовал за ваш ответ :) Ответом более ранним, отвечающим на мой вопрос, был  от Xander

Comment: @Pavel, не заметил другой ответ :) (и тоже проголосовал, т.к. хорошо объяснено и не так замудрена обертка :))